# I want to change the default saved location

Tags: windows, folder-redirection

I deal with this problem since 1 day, i need to change the default path for any app for my RDS Windows Server.
For exemple : "notepad" have to show me the H: drive when i click on "save as", same for "notepad++", or another app.
I've tried GPO, but it exist only for office, registry is full of parameters affecting only the folder redirection...
Thx you !

Answer (score 0):

How to change the default save location in Windows 10

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Click on System and then on "Storage" from the side-bar on the left.
3. Scroll down to the bottom of the page, where it says "More Storage Settings".
4. Click on the text that reads "Change where new content is saved".

You are taken to a new screen which displays the default save locations for six different types of data: Apps, Documents, Music, Photos and Videos, Movies and TV Shows, and Maps.

Each of these options is set to "This PC" by default. To change the default save location click on the menu next to a data type and pick one of the available locations from the menu that opens; Windows 10Â lists all partitions that are available on the computer.

[image]

[image]

If you want to change the save location of Apps, simply click the button next to the icon and select a different drive. Click on the apply button which appears. You will see a progress cursor, wait for a few seconds and it should be done.Â  You will have to repeat this for each of the 6 options if you want to change the save location for each of the data types.

Once you have done this, Windows 10 will save the data to the selected partition. You may have to re-open existing applications for the change to be reflected though.

Note: Windows will still create its Documents folder for each of the selected drives. It will be created in the following format: "Username\Content Type". For e.g. selecting D: as the new location for pictures on my computer created the folder in D:\Ashwin\Pictures. It's too bad that you can't pick a custom folder for the saved data, but this option should be fine for most users.

Windows 10 allows you to pick different partitions for different categories. Continuing with the previous example, you could select a different drive for Documents, say E:. You could set Music to be saved on F: and so on. It also lets you select other hard drives installed on the computer. So, you can use them for saving content as well.

But what about USB hard drives? Can I use those? If you have an external drive connected to the computer, you will see it listed as well. But I'd really only recommend using it for the save location, if the drive will be permanently connected to the computer.

Information source [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/10/14/how-to-change-the-default-save-location-in-windows-10/)

Comment: thanks you for this info, but that was not exactly what i was expecting, the true answer was about **homepath in active directory** ! ive find it after 2 days of research, but i keep in mind your solution !